# Not bound to a valid camera [Image Capture] Camera X error in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When using image analysis to determine smiling, blink faces, I always have that error..

Not Bound To A valid camera: ImageCapture CameraX

```
@Composable
fun FaceDetectorCameraView(
hasPassedAllChecks: Boolean,
onImageCaptured: (Uri) -> Unit,
onErrorFace: (String) -> Unit,
executor: Executor,
doProcessFace: (List<Face>) -> Unit,
onError: (ImageCaptureException) -> Unit 
) {

val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
val context = LocalContext.current
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
val previewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }
val imageCapture: ImageCapture = remember { ImageCapture.Builder().build() }
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(Size(previewView.width, previewView.height))
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .setImageQueueDepth(10)
    .build()
    .apply {
        setAnalyzer(executor, FaceAnalyzer(
            object : FaceAnalyzerCallback{
                override fun processFace(faces: List<Face>) {
                    doProcessFace(faces)
                }
                override fun errorFace(error: String) {
                    onErrorFace(error)
                }

            }
        ))
    }

LaunchedEffect(cameraSelector) {
    val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis,
    )
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
}


AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .requiredHeightIn(80.dp)
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 10.dp),
    factory = { ctx ->
        previewView
    },
)

if(hasPassedAllChecks){
    LaunchedEffect(true){
        delay(1500)
        takePhoto(
            contentResolver = context.contentResolver,
            imageCapture = imageCapture,
            executor = executor,
            onImageCaptured = onImageCaptured,
            onError = onError
        )
    }
}
```

**cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis)**

This will throw that error but:

**cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)**

Works

This is how I am using the function:

```
 FaceDetectorCameraView(
                        hasPassedAllChecks = hasPassedAllChecks,
                        onImageCaptured = {
                            onImageTaken(it)
                        },
                        onErrorFace = {},
                        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                        doProcessFace = doProcessFace,
                        onError = {
                             Toast.makeText(context, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        },
                    )
```